# In Angular 7, ViewChild is undefined when using in *ngIf

Tags: angular7, angular-ng-if, viewchild

When using ViewChild in *ngIf directive, I'm getting Button as undefined. but When i checked the logs, it shows me something like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpb16.png

In my case, its still not working. Can someone help here ?

HTML Code

```
<div *ngIf="someCondition()">
<div class="row top-container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1 class="text-center">Registered </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="pull-right header-buttons-container">
        <button #registerPartnerButton id="registerPartner" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  (click)="registerUser()">Register</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS Code

```
registerButton: ElementRef;
@ViewChildren('registerPartnerButton') set someDummyName(content: ElementRef) {
    this.registerPartnerButton = content;
  };
constructor(changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Issue:
Ever after applying above solutions, i'm getting registerPartnerButton as undefined. but When i checked the logs, it shows me something like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpb16.png

I'm expecting ViewChild must not be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
Finally I fixed it by applying below solution:

registerButton: ElementRef;
@ViewChildren('registerPartnerButton') set setButton(content: QueryList<ElementRef>) 
  {
    if(content.length > 0) {
     this.registerButton = content.first;
     // do further actions
    }
  };
```